# machine learning- Hoeffding’s inequality and PAC Model

Tags: machine-learning

I have the following Question:
A speed-dating event consists of n women and n men. An event has many rounds: In a round, each woman meets one man for 5 minutes, and decides whether to go out on a real date with the man. 
In the first round, 50% of the women agreed to a date, and in the second round, 40% of the women agreed to a date. The third round is about to begin.

Suppose we view all the women in the first round as Bernoulli random variables from distribution D1, with probability of agreeing p1. 
We view all the women in the second round as Bernoulli random variables from distribution D2, with probability of agreeing p2. And we view the women in the third round as Bernoulli random variables from distribution D3, with probability of agreeing p3.

I need to find a minimum value of δ for which the following theorem holds:
Theorem: With probability 1- δ, p1≠p2.
This means that the probability of agreeing to a date depends on the round.

I'm very new to this topic so I would like to get some advice on how should I view this question,where do I begin,is there any theorem I should use in order to solve it?I suppose I should use Hoeffding’s inequality for this,but I find it hard to see the connection.
Any advice or help would be appreciated

Comment: Where did you encounter this exercise?  Can you credit the source?  What did you try?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.  "I have an exercise but I don't know how to get started" questions often aren't an ideal fit here; generic advice is to study the related material and see if you understand all the concepts, and if not, ask about the concepts. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: As it stands, the question doesn't make any sense.  p1 and p2 are whatever they are, so it doesn't make sense to ask about the probability that they are different.  I suggest you try to make sense what the underlying random experiment / probability space is.  What's the sample space?  What is the experiment / random process?